# Determining BSS Size on Object File

Tags: c, gcc, linker

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) mentions that "the bss section typically includes all uninitialized variables declared at file scope." Given the following file:

```
int uninit;

int main() {
    uninit = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this to an executable I see the bss segment filled properly:

```
$ gcc prog1.c -o prog1
$ size prog1
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1115        552       8    1675     68b prog1
```

However if I compile it as an object file I don't see the bss segment (I'd expect it to be 4):

```
$ gcc -c prog1.c
$ size prog1.o 
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
  72          0       0      72      48 prog1.o
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

I am using gcc version 4.8.1.

Comment: `void main()`? Still?

Comment: yes, not sure what drove me to write that. fixed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we use `readelf -s` to look at the symbol table, we'll see:

```
$ readelf -s prog1.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS bss.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     8: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  COM uninit      <<<<
     9: 0000000000000000    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main
```

We see that your `uninit` symbol ("variable") is, at this stage, a "common" symbol. It has not yet been "assigned" to the BSS.

See this question for more information on "common" symbols: [What does "COM" means in the Ndx column of the .symtab section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137522/what-does-com-means-in-the-ndx-column-of-the-symtab-section)

Once your final executable is linked together, it will be put in the BSS as you expected.

---

You can bypass this behavior by passing the [`-fno-common`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) flag to GCC:

```
$ gcc -fno-common -c bss.c
$ size bss.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     72       0       4      76      4c bss.o
```

---

Instead, you could mark `uninit` as `static`.  This way, the compiler will know that no other `.o` file can refer to it, so it will not be a "common" symbol. Instead, it will be placed into the BSS immediately, as you expected:

```
$ cat bss.c
```

```
static int uninit;

int main() {
    uninit = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -c bss.c 
$ size bss.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     72       0       4      76      4c bss.o
```

Comment: Your edits are also quite excellent notes. Why stackoverflow is awesome :D

Comment: You're welcome. It was a fun exercise for me, because I too was confused by what you were seeing.